# Why does my code only work inside of a DispatchQueue.main.async block?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I wrote this code to select all the text when a user begins editing a `UITextField`:

```
@IBAction func onEditingBegin(_ sender: Any) {
    print("editing began")
    let textfield = sender as! UITextField
    textfield.selectAll(nil)
}
```

But it wouldn't work until I enclosed the `textfield.selectAll(nil)` line in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    textfield.selectAll(nil)
}
```

Why is that?

### Update:

I printed out the name of the thread in `onEditingBegin()` and this was the result:

```
<NSThread: 0x60800006c880>{number = 1, name = main}
```

So it seems that it is already being fired on the main thread, but the code is still not working unless `textfield.selectAll()` is called inside of the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block.

Comment: Could you try "let" to "Var textfield = sender as! UITextField"

Comment: @AvijitNagare tried that. still didn't work

Comment: On which event is the handler mapped?

Comment: @AvijitNagare also when doing that i get the warning that "'textfield' was never mutated, consider changing to 'let' constant"

Comment: @Sulthan `Editing Did Begin`

Comment: Try changing the async to sync and see if it continues to work. ( dispatchQueue - sync in same thread is supposed to be same as just writing something in that line of code.)

Comment: @shashank get an error: `Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXCI386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)`

Answer (score 0):

'cause all the UI modifications happen only in the main thread...

If you change your UI in a different thread the result is impredictable: it may never happen or been shown later.

Comment: But Wouldn't IBAction execute on mainThread by default?

Comment: @shashank not if it's called from a background thread. If it is triggered from a button then it should be, yes.

Comment: I'm not that sure about all the IBActions: some (like this one) are async by nature: the "edit begin" don't stop the main thread for sure so my guess is that it run in a separate thread...

Comment: this doesn't provide an explanation as to why the code works only when inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block

Comment: @shashank it's definitely executing on the main thread -- see update